# displaying status of questionnaire answers within react using a .map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been stuck on this issue for quite some time now and any advice could go a long way here.

I have a page which creates an array of objects which when console logged looks like below.

```
0: {answer: "yes", question: "Is the keyboard set to a suitable height", state: "Accepted", email: "henryjohnpeters@gmail.com", questionId: 30, …}
1: {answer: "yes", question: "Is it possible to find a comfortable typing postion?", state: "Accepted", email: "henryjohnpeters@gmail.com", questionId: 31, …}
2: {answer: "yes", question: "Do you have a good keyboard technique?", state: "Accepted", email: "henryjohnpeters@gmail.com", questionId: 32, …}
3: {answer: "yes", question: "Are the characters on the keyboard clear and readable?", state: "Accepted", email: "henryjohnpeters@gmail.com", questionId: 33, …}
4: {answer: "yes", question: "Is your mouse or other pointing device suitable to the task you're using it for?", state: "Accepted", email: "henryjohnpeters@gmail.com", questionId: 34, …}
5: {answer: "yes", question: "Is the mouse (or other pointing device) located sufficently close to you?  ", state: "Accepted", email: "henryjohnpeters@gmail.com", questionId: 35, …}
6: {answer: "yes", question: "Is there support for your wrist and forearm when using the mouse(or other pointing device)", state: "Accepted", email: "henryjohnpeters@gmail.com", questionId: 36, …}
7: {answer: "yes", question: "Does the mouse (or other pointing device) work smoothly at a speed that suits you?", state: "Accepted", email: "henryjohnpeters@gmail.com", questionId: 37, …}
8: {answer: "yes", question: "Can you easily adjust the software settings for speed and accuracy of the pointer?", state: "Accepted", email: "henryjohnpeters@gmail.com", questionId: 38, …}
9: {answer: "yes", question: "Are the characters on your screen clear and readable?", state: "Accepted", email: "henryjohnpeters@gmail.com", questionId: 39, …}
10: {answer: "yes", question: "Is the text size on your screen confortable to read?", state: "Accepted", email: "henryjohnpeters@gmail.com", questionId: 40, …}
11: {answer: "yes", question: "Is the image on your screen free from flicker and jitter?", state: "Accepted", email: "henryjohnpeters@gmail.com", questionId: 41, …}
12: {answer: "yes", question: "Is your screen's specification suitable for its intended use?", state: "Accepted", email: "henryjohnpeters@gmail.com", questionId: 42, …}
13: {answer: "yes", question: "Is the brightness and/or contrast on your screen adjustable?", state: "Accepted", email: "henryjohnpeters@gmail.com", questionId: 43, …}
length: 14
```

When expanded each object looks like changing depending on response. (ignore the state property this will be removed.)

```
answer: "yes"
question: "Is the keyboard set to a suitable height"
state: "Accepted"
email: "johns@gmail.com"
questionId: 30
workStation: "skrt"
accepted: "0"
date: "2020-2-20 17:11:3.616 "
```

This array is called results.

I then have a onclick function when the questionnaire is submitted shown below

```
submitAnswers() {
    let completeToken = "";
    if (questionCounter == this.state.questions.length) {
      var today = new Date(),
        date = `${today.getUTCFullYear()}-${today.getUTCMonth() +
          1}-${today.getUTCDate()} ${today.getHours()}:${today.getMinutes()}:${today.getSeconds()}.${today.getMilliseconds()} `;

      if (results.find(q => q.Accepted == 1)) {
        completeToken = "Not Complete";
      }
      console.log(completeToken);

      const data = {
        results,
        date
      };

      fetch("/post-question-answers/", {
        method: "POST", // or 'PUT'
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json,",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      }).then(response => {
        console.log("response before it is broken down " + response);

        return response.json();
      });

      // window.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/completed-assessment";
    } else {
      alert("Please enter all of The questions");
    }
  }
```

The issue here is I am trying to do this

```
if (results.find(q => q.accepted == 1)) {
        completeToken = "Complete";
      }
      console.log(completeToken);
```

It is searching within these objects for a .accepted = 1 which means that it is an accepted question. However my console.log simply displays nothing.

Please help if you can I have been struggling with this all day

Comment: Maybe none of the questions have been accepted...

Comment: It's also not clear from your code how the `results` variable even comes into being. You dont' do anything like `const results = this.state.results;` anywhere

Comment: the results.find block in your submitAnswers code doesn't match the snippet below, it has 'q.Accepted' instead of 'q.accepted'. Is that a typo?

Comment: Sorry that awas a typo for this question it is not how I have it in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a typo q.Accepted (Capital A), where as in object description it is mentioned as "accepted", hence undefined == 1 which is always false and in console log completedToken value is "" (empty string) so nothing is visible in result.

Comment: In the code I have it this way but it is not working

Comment: make sure you have at least one object in results array which has accepted value 1, I have tried it and it is printing the completedToken value, if still have an issue please share the demo snippet on react playground.